# Как задать высоту у селекта?

Tags: html

Как задать высоту у селекта? `<select>` так же как увеличить высоту у оптион внутри него?

Answer (score 1):

Кросбраузерно никак!!! Только эмуляция кастомного селекта.

Скачайте jquery плагины для стилизации и там а API будет указано как увеличить величину селекта, либо полазь в исходниках.

Answer (score 1):

Padding попробуйте.

Comment: IE8 не фурычит .

Answer (score 0):

Разве CSS-ом нельзя ?

```
 <style>
       #selectStyle select
       {
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
       }
    </style>
    <div id="selectStyle">
           <select>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
           </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: А разве высоту options тоже можно установить?

Answer (score 0):

https://xhtml.ru/2021/css/customization-of-the-select-field/ посмотрите этот сайт,или же просто исползуйте font-size

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/874965)